# Url Xml Parsing In c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

i want to get a data from a xml [site](https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml) but i want spesific data i want to get USD/TRY, GBP/TRY and EUR/TRY Forex Buying values i dont know how to split those values from the data i have a test console program and the is like this

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string XmlUrl = "https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml";
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(XmlUrl);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);

                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                            Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                        Console.Write(">");
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

how can i split the values from i want from the xml

My desired output is this

```
public class ParaBirimi
    {
        public decimal ForexBuying { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }//Values like USD GBP EUR
    }
```

class to a list

Comment: Please edit your question and add a desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

Here is your starting point. You can extend it to read any attribute or element.

**XML fragment**

```
<Tarih_Date Tarih="28.05.2021" Date="05/28/2021" Bulten_No="2021/100">
    <Currency CrossOrder="0" Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD">
        <Unit>1</Unit>
        <Isim>ABD DOLARI</Isim>
        <CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
        <ForexBuying>8.5496</ForexBuying>
        <ForexSelling>8.5651</ForexSelling>
        <BanknoteBuying>8.5437</BanknoteBuying>
        <BanknoteSelling>8.5779</BanknoteSelling>
        <CrossRateUSD/>
        <CrossRateOther/>
    </Currency>
    <Currency CrossOrder="1" Kod="AUD" CurrencyCode="AUD">
        <Unit>1</Unit>
        <Isim>AVUSTRALYA DOLARI</Isim>
        <CurrencyName>AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
        <ForexBuying>6.5843</ForexBuying>
        <ForexSelling>6.6272</ForexSelling>
        <BanknoteBuying>6.5540</BanknoteBuying>
        <BanknoteSelling>6.6670</BanknoteSelling>
        <CrossRateUSD>1.2954</CrossRateUSD>
        <CrossRateOther/>
    </Currency>
    ...
</Tarih_Date>
```

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string URL = @"https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(URL);
    
    foreach (XElement elem in xdoc.Descendants("Currency"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CrossOrder: '{1}', Kod: '{1}', CurrencyCode: '{2}', Isim: '{3}', CurrencyName: '{4}'{0}"
            , Environment.NewLine
            , elem.Attribute("CrossOrder").Value
            , elem.Attribute("Kod").Value
            , elem.Attribute("CurrencyCode").Value
            , elem.Element("Isim").Value
            , elem.Element("CurrencyName").Value
            );
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
CrossOrder: '0', Kod: '0', CurrencyCode: 'USD', Isim: 'USD', CurrencyName: 'ABD DOLARI'

CrossOrder: '1', Kod: '1', CurrencyCode: 'AUD', Isim: 'AUD', CurrencyName: 'AVUSTRALYA DOLARI'
```

Comment: @OytunTur, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.